# how to add all individual Untitled.cpp from every folder to .gitignore?

Tags: git, github

Suppose this is the structure of my file system.

```
root/
    folder1/
       Untitled1.cpp
       code.cpp
    folder2/
       Untitled2.cpp
       Untitled3.cpp
    .git
    .gitignore
```

i want to add all untitled.cpp files to gitignore. I don't want to ignore them manually always. For ignoring .o and .exe I've used `*.exe *.o` . But for `untitled(0-9)` what should be the expression i should write in .gitignore file? Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), this should do the trick:

```
**/root/Untitled?.cpp
```

> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories.
>
> Git treats the pattern as a shell glob: "*" matches anything except "/", "?" matches any one character except "/"